# Basemap - Colorbar legend for state colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a basemap map which loads in a shapefile of US states, for each state I am mapping a certain color to a Polygon that is the shape of the state and then adding this to the plot. Adding these polygons and colors is successful but the problem I have is that I want a legend that displays the gradient between the maximum color and minimum color but I can't seem to work out how. The colorbar() method wants a mappable which I'm not sure is possible for my example as I am using Polygons to colour the map rather than imshow() or contours. Below is the code I have written.

```
mapAx.set_title("# of votes for Trump")

mapVotes = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)     
mapVotes.readshapefile('states', name = 'states', drawbounds=True)

colorVotes = plt.get_cmap('Blues')

trump = {
'New Hampshire': 100406,
'Iowa': 45427,
'South Carolina' : 239851,
'Nevada' : 34531}

state_names = []
for shape_dict in mapVotes.states_info:
    state_names.append(shape_dict['STATE_NAME'])


for state, value in trump.items():
    #print("{} {}".format(state, value)
    try:
        seg = mapVotes.states[state_names.index('{}'.format(state))]
        color = colorVotes(value/float(trump[max(trump)]))
        poly= Polygon(seg, facecolor=color, edgecolor=color)
        mapAx.add_patch(poly)
    except ValueError:
        pass

plt.show()
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the shapefiles so that I can recreate your code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! [Here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f7f805eb65eb4ab787a0a3e1116ca7e5) is where I downloaded my shapefiles from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api example for [patch_collection](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html) shows how to do a colorbar. Essentially, you add all your patches to a list and then pass that into PatchCollection, which returns a scalermappable. In your specific case:

```
#empty lists for colors and polygons
colors = []
patches = []

for state, value in trump.items():
#print("{} {}".format(state, value)
try:
    seg = mapVotes.states[state_names.index('{}'.format(state))]
    color = colorVotes(value/float(trump[max(trump)]))
    colors.append(color) # add colors to colors list
    poly = Polygon(seg, facecolor=color, edgecolor=color)
    patches.append(poly) #add polygon to patches list
    mapAx.add_patch(poly)
except ValueError:
    pass

#new code
#patches collection is a scalermappable
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=colorVotes)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))
cb = fig.colorbar(p)
```

And then modify cb to show the correct values. Or create a mcolor norm based on your coloring scheme and pass that into  PatchCollection or colorbar. But the above code yields:
[image]